# SCCM Collection Hardware Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportbuilder3.0, sccm

I found this report and I wanted to be able to change it so that I can use it on specific collections. I know it's like one line of code that needs to be added but I'm not sure how or where to put it. Can anyone help?

Thanks

```
DECLARE @Today AS DATE
SET @Today = GETDATE()

DECLARE @BackInTime AS DATE
SET @BackInTime = DATEADD(DAY, -30, @Today )

SELECT DISTINCT
 SYS.ResourceID,
 SYS.Name0 'Name', 
 SYS.AD_Site_Name0 'ADSite', 
 CS.UserName0 'User Name',
 CASE
 WHEN U.TopConsoleUser0 = '-1' OR U.TopConsoleUser0 IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
 ELSE U.TopConsoleUser0
 END AS TopUser,
 REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE (OS.Caption0, 'Microsoft Windows','Win')),'Enterprise','EE') ),'Standard','ST')),'Microsoft®','')),'Server','SRV')),'Windows','Win') OS, 
 REPLACE (OS.CSDVersion0,'Service Pack','SP') 'Service Pack',
 CS.Manufacturer0 'Manufacturer',
 CS.Model0 Model,
 BIOS.SerialNumber0 'Serial Number', 
 CONVERT (DATE,BIOS.ReleaseDate0) AS BIOSDate, 
 BIOS.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0 AS BIOSVersion, 
 (SELECT CONVERT(DATE,SYS.Creation_Date0)) 'Managed Date', 
 SUM(ISNULL(RAM.Capacity0,0)) 'Memory (MB)', 
 COUNT(RAM.ResourceID) '# Memory Slots',
 REPLACE (cs.SystemType0,'-based PC','') 'Type',
 SUM(D.Size0) / 1024 AS 'Disk Size GB',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), OS.LastBootUpTime0, 100) AS 'Last Reboot Date/Time',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), OS.InstallDate0, 101) AS 'Install Date',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), WS.LastHWScan, 101) AS 'Last Hardware Inventory',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), CH.LastOnline, 101) AS 'Last Seen Online',
 SYS.Client_Version0 as 'SCCM Agent Version',
 CPU.Manufacturer AS 'CPU Man.',
 CPU.[Number of CPUs] AS '# of CPUs',
 CPU.[Number of Cores per CPU] AS '# of Cores per CPU',
 CPU.[Logical CPU Count] AS 'Logical CPU Count', 
 US.ScanTime AS ' Windows Updates Scan Time' ,
 US.LastErrorCode AS ' Windows Updates Last Error Code' ,
 US.LastScanPackageLocation AS ' Windows Updates Last Package Location' ,
 CASE SE.ChassisTypes0 
 WHEN '1' THEN 'Other'
 WHEN '2' THEN 'Unknown'
 WHEN '3' THEN 'Desktop'
 WHEN '4' THEN 'Low Profile Desktop'
 WHEN '5' THEN 'Pizza Box'
 WHEN '6' THEN 'Mini Tower'
 WHEN '7' THEN 'Tower'
 WHEN '8' THEN 'Portable'
 WHEN '9' THEN 'Laptop'
 WHEN '10' THEN 'Notebook'
 WHEN '11' THEN 'Hand Held'
 WHEN '12' THEN 'Docking Station'
 WHEN '13' THEN 'All in One'
 WHEN '14' THEN 'Sub Notebook'
 WHEN '15' THEN 'Space-Saving'
 WHEN '16' THEN 'Lunch Box'
 WHEN '17' THEN 'Main System Chassis'
 WHEN '18' THEN 'Expansion Chassis'
 WHEN '19' THEN 'SubChassis'
 WHEN '20' THEN 'Bus Expansion Chassis'
 WHEN '21' THEN 'Peripheral Chassis'
 WHEN '22' THEN 'Storage Chassis'
 WHEN '23' THEN 'Rack Mount Chassis'
 WHEN '24' THEN 'Sealed-Case PC'
 ELSE 'Undefinded'
 END AS 'PC Type'
FROM
 v_R_System SYS
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT
 Name0,
 MAX(Creation_Date0) AS Creation_Date
 FROM
 dbo.v_R_System

 GROUP BY
 Name0
 ) AS CleanSystem
 ON SYS.Name0 = CleanSystem.Name0 AND SYS.Creation_Date0 = CleanSystem.Creation_Date
 LEFT JOIN v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM CS 
 ON SYS.ResourceID=cs.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN v_GS_PC_BIOS BIOS 
 ON SYS.ResourceID=bios.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT
 A.ResourceID,
 MAX(A.[InstallDate0]) AS [InstallDate0]
 FROM
 v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM A
 GROUP BY
 A.ResourceID
 ) AS X
 ON SYS.ResourceID = X.ResourceID
 INNER JOIN v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM OS 
 ON X.ResourceID=OS.ResourceID AND X.InstallDate0 = OS.InstallDate0
 LEFT JOIN v_GS_PHYSICAL_MEMORY RAM 
 ON SYS.ResourceID=ram.ResourceID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK D
 ON SYS.ResourceID = D.ResourceID AND D.DriveType0 = 3
 LEFT OUTER JOIN v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP U
 ON SYS.ResourceID = U.ResourceID 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE SE ON SYS.ResourceID = SE.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.v_GS_ENCRYPTABLE_VOLUME En ON SYS.ResourceID = En.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS WS ON SYS.ResourceID = WS.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN v_CH_ClientSummary CH
 ON SYS.ResourceID = CH.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT
 DISTINCT(CPU.SystemName0) AS [System Name],
 CPU.Manufacturer0 AS Manufacturer,
 CPU.ResourceID,
 CPU.Name0 AS Name,
 COUNT(CPU.ResourceID) AS [Number of CPUs],
 CPU.NumberOfCores0 AS [Number of Cores per CPU],
 CPU.NumberOfLogicalProcessors0 AS [Logical CPU Count]
 FROM [dbo].[v_GS_PROCESSOR] CPU
 GROUP BY
 CPU.SystemName0,
 CPU.Manufacturer0,
 CPU.Name0,
 CPU.NumberOfCores0,
 CPU.NumberOfLogicalProcessors0,
 CPU.ResourceID
 ) CPU
 ON CPU.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus US
 ON US.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID
WHERE SYS.obsolete0=0 AND SYS.client0=1 AND SYS.obsolete0=0 AND SYS.active0=1 AND
 CH.LastOnline BETWEEN @BackInTime AND GETDATE()

 GROUP BY
 SYS.Creation_Date0 ,
 SYS.Name0 , 
 SYS.ResourceID ,
 SYS.AD_Site_Name0 ,
 CS.UserName0 ,
 REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE (OS.Caption0, 'Microsoft Windows','Win')),'Enterprise','EE') ),'Standard','ST')),'Microsoft®','')),'Server','SRV')),'Windows','Win'), 
 REPLACE (OS.CSDVersion0,'Service Pack','SP'),
 CS.Manufacturer0 ,
 CS.Model0 ,
 BIOS.SerialNumber0 ,
 REPLACE (cs.SystemType0,'-based PC','') ,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), OS.LastBootUpTime0, 100) ,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), OS.InstallDate0, 101) ,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), WS.LastHWScan, 101),
 CASE
 WHEN U.TopConsoleUser0 = '-1' OR U.TopConsoleUser0 IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
 ELSE U.TopConsoleUser0
 END,
 CPU.Manufacturer, 
 CPU.[Number of CPUs] ,
 CPU.[Number of Cores per CPU], 
 CPU.[Logical CPU Count],
 US.ScanTime ,
 US.LastErrorCode ,
 US.LastScanPackageLocation ,
 CASE SE.ChassisTypes0 
 WHEN '1' THEN 'Other'
 WHEN '2' THEN 'Unknown'
 WHEN '3' THEN 'Desktop'
 WHEN '4' THEN 'Low Profile Desktop'
 WHEN '5' THEN 'Pizza Box'
 WHEN '6' THEN 'Mini Tower'
 WHEN '7' THEN 'Tower'
 WHEN '8' THEN 'Portable'
 WHEN '9' THEN 'Laptop'
 WHEN '10' THEN 'Notebook'
 WHEN '11' THEN 'Hand Held'
 WHEN '12' THEN 'Docking Station'
 WHEN '13' THEN 'All in One'
 WHEN '14' THEN 'Sub Notebook'
 WHEN '15' THEN 'Space-Saving'
 WHEN '16' THEN 'Lunch Box'
 WHEN '17' THEN 'Main System Chassis'
 WHEN '18' THEN 'Expansion Chassis'
 WHEN '19' THEN 'SubChassis'
 WHEN '20' THEN 'Bus Expansion Chassis'
 WHEN '21' THEN 'Peripheral Chassis'
 WHEN '22' THEN 'Storage Chassis'
 WHEN '23' THEN 'Rack Mount Chassis'
 WHEN '24' THEN 'Sealed-Case PC'
 ELSE 'Undefinded'
 END ,
 CONVERT (DATE,BIOS.ReleaseDate0) , 
 BIOS.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0 ,
 SYS.Client_Version0 ,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26) ,CH.LastOnline, 101)
 ORDER BY SYS.Name0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition is added into the Where clause. In order to specify the collection name, we also need to join Collection views, here I joined v_FullCollectionMembership and v_Collection.  Change the collection name *COL.Name = 'Win7'* to your own Collection name here.

```
join v_FullCollectionMembership FCM on FCM.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID
 JOIN v_Collection COL ON COL.CollectionID = FCM.CollectionID 
WHERE SYS.obsolete0=0 AND SYS.client0=1 AND SYS.obsolete0=0 AND SYS.active0=1 AND
 CH.LastOnline BETWEEN @BackInTime AND GETDATE() AND COL.Name = 'Win7'
```

Full query as below:

```
DECLARE @Today AS DATE
SET @Today = GETDATE()

DECLARE @BackInTime AS DATE
SET @BackInTime = DATEADD(DAY, -30, @Today )

SELECT DISTINCT
 SYS.ResourceID,
 SYS.Name0 'Name', 
 SYS.AD_Site_Name0 'ADSite', 
 CS.UserName0 'User Name',
 CASE
 WHEN U.TopConsoleUser0 = '-1' OR U.TopConsoleUser0 IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
 ELSE U.TopConsoleUser0
 END AS TopUser,
 REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE (OS.Caption0, 'Microsoft Windows','Win')),'Enterprise','EE') ),'Standard','ST')),'Microsoft®','')),'Server','SRV')),'Windows','Win') OS, 
 REPLACE (OS.CSDVersion0,'Service Pack','SP') 'Service Pack',
 CS.Manufacturer0 'Manufacturer',
 CS.Model0 Model,
 BIOS.SerialNumber0 'Serial Number', 
 CONVERT (DATE,BIOS.ReleaseDate0) AS BIOSDate, 
 BIOS.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0 AS BIOSVersion, 
 (SELECT CONVERT(DATE,SYS.Creation_Date0)) 'Managed Date', 
 SUM(ISNULL(RAM.Capacity0,0)) 'Memory (MB)', 
 COUNT(RAM.ResourceID) '# Memory Slots',
 REPLACE (cs.SystemType0,'-based PC','') 'Type',
 SUM(D.Size0) / 1024 AS 'Disk Size GB',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), OS.LastBootUpTime0, 100) AS 'Last Reboot Date/Time',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), OS.InstallDate0, 101) AS 'Install Date',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), WS.LastHWScan, 101) AS 'Last Hardware Inventory',
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), CH.LastOnline, 101) AS 'Last Seen Online',
 SYS.Client_Version0 as 'SCCM Agent Version',
 CPU.Manufacturer AS 'CPU Man.',
 CPU.[Number of CPUs] AS '# of CPUs',
 CPU.[Number of Cores per CPU] AS '# of Cores per CPU',
 CPU.[Logical CPU Count] AS 'Logical CPU Count', 
 US.ScanTime AS ' Windows Updates Scan Time' ,
 US.LastErrorCode AS ' Windows Updates Last Error Code' ,
 US.LastScanPackageLocation AS ' Windows Updates Last Package Location' ,
 CASE SE.ChassisTypes0 
 WHEN '1' THEN 'Other'
 WHEN '2' THEN 'Unknown'
 WHEN '3' THEN 'Desktop'
 WHEN '4' THEN 'Low Profile Desktop'
 WHEN '5' THEN 'Pizza Box'
 WHEN '6' THEN 'Mini Tower'
 WHEN '7' THEN 'Tower'
 WHEN '8' THEN 'Portable'
 WHEN '9' THEN 'Laptop'
 WHEN '10' THEN 'Notebook'
 WHEN '11' THEN 'Hand Held'
 WHEN '12' THEN 'Docking Station'
 WHEN '13' THEN 'All in One'
 WHEN '14' THEN 'Sub Notebook'
 WHEN '15' THEN 'Space-Saving'
 WHEN '16' THEN 'Lunch Box'
 WHEN '17' THEN 'Main System Chassis'
 WHEN '18' THEN 'Expansion Chassis'
 WHEN '19' THEN 'SubChassis'
 WHEN '20' THEN 'Bus Expansion Chassis'
 WHEN '21' THEN 'Peripheral Chassis'
 WHEN '22' THEN 'Storage Chassis'
 WHEN '23' THEN 'Rack Mount Chassis'
 WHEN '24' THEN 'Sealed-Case PC'
 ELSE 'Undefinded'
 END AS 'PC Type'
FROM
 v_R_System SYS
 INNER JOIN (
 SELECT
 Name0,
 MAX(Creation_Date0) AS Creation_Date
 FROM
 dbo.v_R_System

 GROUP BY
 Name0
 ) AS CleanSystem
 ON SYS.Name0 = CleanSystem.Name0 AND SYS.Creation_Date0 = CleanSystem.Creation_Date
 LEFT JOIN v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM CS 
 ON SYS.ResourceID=cs.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN v_GS_PC_BIOS BIOS 
 ON SYS.ResourceID=bios.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT
 A.ResourceID,
 MAX(A.[InstallDate0]) AS [InstallDate0]
 FROM
 v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM A
 GROUP BY
 A.ResourceID
 ) AS X
 ON SYS.ResourceID = X.ResourceID
 INNER JOIN v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM OS 
 ON X.ResourceID=OS.ResourceID AND X.InstallDate0 = OS.InstallDate0
 LEFT JOIN v_GS_PHYSICAL_MEMORY RAM 
 ON SYS.ResourceID=ram.ResourceID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_GS_LOGICAL_DISK D
 ON SYS.ResourceID = D.ResourceID AND D.DriveType0 = 3
 LEFT OUTER JOIN v_GS_SYSTEM_CONSOLE_USAGE_MAXGROUP U
 ON SYS.ResourceID = U.ResourceID 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE SE ON SYS.ResourceID = SE.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.v_GS_ENCRYPTABLE_VOLUME En ON SYS.ResourceID = En.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN dbo.v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS WS ON SYS.ResourceID = WS.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN v_CH_ClientSummary CH
 ON SYS.ResourceID = CH.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT
 DISTINCT(CPU.SystemName0) AS [System Name],
 CPU.Manufacturer0 AS Manufacturer,
 CPU.ResourceID,
 CPU.Name0 AS Name,
 COUNT(CPU.ResourceID) AS [Number of CPUs],
 CPU.NumberOfCores0 AS [Number of Cores per CPU],
 CPU.NumberOfLogicalProcessors0 AS [Logical CPU Count]
 FROM [dbo].[v_GS_PROCESSOR] CPU
 GROUP BY
 CPU.SystemName0,
 CPU.Manufacturer0,
 CPU.Name0,
 CPU.NumberOfCores0,
 CPU.NumberOfLogicalProcessors0,
 CPU.ResourceID
 ) CPU
 ON CPU.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID
 LEFT JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus US
 ON US.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID
 join v_FullCollectionMembership FCM on FCM.ResourceID = SYS.ResourceID
 JOIN v_Collection COL ON COL.CollectionID = FCM.CollectionID 
WHERE SYS.obsolete0=0 AND SYS.client0=1 AND SYS.obsolete0=0 AND SYS.active0=1 AND
 CH.LastOnline BETWEEN @BackInTime AND GETDATE() AND COL.Name = 'Win7'

 GROUP BY
 SYS.Creation_Date0 ,
 SYS.Name0 , 
 SYS.ResourceID ,
 SYS.AD_Site_Name0 ,
 CS.UserName0 ,
 REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE((REPLACE (OS.Caption0, 'Microsoft Windows','Win')),'Enterprise','EE') ),'Standard','ST')),'Microsoft®','')),'Server','SRV')),'Windows','Win'), 
 REPLACE (OS.CSDVersion0,'Service Pack','SP'),
 CS.Manufacturer0 ,
 CS.Model0 ,
 BIOS.SerialNumber0 ,
 REPLACE (cs.SystemType0,'-based PC','') ,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), OS.LastBootUpTime0, 100) ,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), OS.InstallDate0, 101) ,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), WS.LastHWScan, 101),
 CASE
 WHEN U.TopConsoleUser0 = '-1' OR U.TopConsoleUser0 IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
 ELSE U.TopConsoleUser0
 END,
 CPU.Manufacturer, 
 CPU.[Number of CPUs] ,
 CPU.[Number of Cores per CPU], 
 CPU.[Logical CPU Count],
 US.ScanTime ,
 US.LastErrorCode ,
 US.LastScanPackageLocation ,
 CASE SE.ChassisTypes0 
 WHEN '1' THEN 'Other'
 WHEN '2' THEN 'Unknown'
 WHEN '3' THEN 'Desktop'
 WHEN '4' THEN 'Low Profile Desktop'
 WHEN '5' THEN 'Pizza Box'
 WHEN '6' THEN 'Mini Tower'
 WHEN '7' THEN 'Tower'
 WHEN '8' THEN 'Portable'
 WHEN '9' THEN 'Laptop'
 WHEN '10' THEN 'Notebook'
 WHEN '11' THEN 'Hand Held'
 WHEN '12' THEN 'Docking Station'
 WHEN '13' THEN 'All in One'
 WHEN '14' THEN 'Sub Notebook'
 WHEN '15' THEN 'Space-Saving'
 WHEN '16' THEN 'Lunch Box'
 WHEN '17' THEN 'Main System Chassis'
 WHEN '18' THEN 'Expansion Chassis'
 WHEN '19' THEN 'SubChassis'
 WHEN '20' THEN 'Bus Expansion Chassis'
 WHEN '21' THEN 'Peripheral Chassis'
 WHEN '22' THEN 'Storage Chassis'
 WHEN '23' THEN 'Rack Mount Chassis'
 WHEN '24' THEN 'Sealed-Case PC'
 ELSE 'Undefinded'
 END ,
 CONVERT (DATE,BIOS.ReleaseDate0) , 
 BIOS.SMBIOSBIOSVersion0 ,
 SYS.Client_Version0 ,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(26) ,CH.LastOnline, 101)
 ORDER BY SYS.Name0
```

Comment: Hi, Just want to know if the answer helps or not, thanks.

Comment: Hi Bifeng,

Yes, it did help. Thank you!